# Remove last 2 commits without delete all data

Tags: git

I need to remove my last two commits but also need to save some data from these commits (one folder). And merge that into my 3rd commit.
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can reset back to two-commits ago using

```
git reset --mixed HEAD~2
```

This will reset the branch but keep all the changes those two commits. Then simply add and commit what you need to save

```
git add <important folder>
git commit -m'added important folder'
```

Comment: --soft would leave all changes 'added' already, better would be --mixed

Comment: Yeah --mixed might work better for this case. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply stop thinking about it in the terms of "removing commits". I'd say:

Note down the current commit ID:

```
git log |head -n1
```

go back two commits,

```
git checkout HEAD~2
```

then check out only your directory

```
git checkout <noted ID> -- yourdirectory/
```

and commit the result:

```
git commit -m "kept the future of yourdirectory/" yourdirectory
```

And if you really want to meddle with an existing commit, use

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10
```

to squash these two commits.

If you really want to (you don't have to) you can `git prune` the dangling commits later on.

Comment: I think it should be HEAD~2 not HEAD~3 - two commits back

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase -i HEAD~2` allows you to edit previous 3 commits.

You probably want to apply the squash command on the interactive shell